# Program Quality control for data sequencing (nanopore)

Tags: nanopore

Hope all of you are fine. I am wondering if exists a program easy to use that can bring me Basic Statistics of Quality Control from raw data made by MinION device (nanopore).

I have read about FASTAQC and Porechop. My sequencing raw data was a result of a metagenomics analysis (16s and 18s). My main objective is only to filter the sequences and obtain a basic statistic about the lenght and the number of sequences ordered by the lenght. Thank you ladies and gentlemen

PD Sorry for my poor english. Day to day i'm trying to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

A simple start would be to use [MinIONQC](https://github.com/roblanf/minion_qc), which is also available via bioconda under the name `r-minionqc`.

Answer (score 1):

I assume raw data is in Fastq format, but ideally you should also use the sequencing_summary.txt file generated by the basecaller. Other alternatives for QC are [PycoQC](https://github.com/a-slide/pycoQC) and [NanoPlot](https://github.com/wdecoster/NanoPlot). I developed and maintain NanoPlot, so let me know if there is something I can help you with.